# Redirect to particular page after payment

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have created a form using "gravity form". And I uses paypal or stripe payment method in it.
I want that when someone pay his/her payment then he/she redirect to some particular URL.

How can I do this ? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution myself. :-)

Here it is :-

```
add_filter( 'gform_paypal_return_url', 'update_url', 10, 4 );
```

function update_url( $url, $form_id, $entry_id, $query ) {

```
return 'https://somedomain.com/?' . $query;
```

}